# Javascript Function to Play Video Asp.net Looping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to loop through a field in the database to return each fields one after another so I am using a foreach tag razor view like so:

```
    @foreach (var nameurl in Model.ListSplash)

    {
     //returns the url one after another on the console  
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Count " + nameurl.Url.Length);
        var url = nameurl.Url.Length;

    <script>

        resetVid = function () {
            //get the Video div and replace with the original video source code
            var videoPanel = document.getElementById('vid');
            videoPanel.innerHTML = '<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/@Model.xxxxdisplay.Url" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
        }

            PlayVid = function () {
                //get the Video div and play new video on button click
                var videoPanel = document.getElementById('vid');
                videoPanel.innerHTML = '<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/@nameurl.Url?autoplay=1&start=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

                //replace video after 8.5 seconds
                //setTimeout(resetVid, 8500);
            }
     </script>
      }
```

My challenge is that it keeps returning the last data in the field when the javascript method is called in the view like so (assuming that each button should return data):

```
<button onclick="PlayVid()">
                            <img src="~/img/cover1.jpg" alt="people" class="img-circle" />
                     </button>
                    <button onclick="PlayVid()">
                        <img src="~/img/cover2.jpg" alt="people" class="img-circle" />
                    </button>
                    <button onclick="PlayVid()">
                        <img src="~/img/cover3.jpg" alt="people" class="img-circle" />
                    </button>
```

I want each button to return a unique url from the table when a button is clicked but the last data keeps returning.
Kindly assist.

Comment: try putting your scripts outside the foreach loop

Comment: had actually but this line of code returns error:videoPanel.innerHTML = '<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/@nameurl.Url?autoplay=1&start=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'; AT nameurl.Url

Comment: Should I assume this question has no answer or direction by the community